# Set UILabel text from values retrieved from php

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, database

I need to automatically get a variable from an existing php file to replace the text of a label when the view controller changes. The change of view controller happens with the push of a button (if this is relevant?) I already made the database on our hosting, and the variables are in place.

```
1) I need to know how to adress the automation problem
2) I need to know how to get the variable from the php file
```

Comment: This is a large topic and not well suited to a single stack overflow question.  Briefly, your PHP script needs to conform to some kind of API and your iOS app needs to know how to fetch teh data from that API.

Comment: James, i dont think the API will do the trick... i've been modeling it in all kind of directions and am thinking of just simple data retraction from a host and placement on a guest-app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP should return the contents in the variable in a format easily consumed by your Objective-C program, for example JSON. So, for example,

```
<?php

// retrieve the value of $result variable any way you want. I'm going to just set the literal

$result = "Hello World!"; 

// now convert to an array

$result_array = array("result" => $result);

// return the json_encoded rendition

echo json_encode($result_array);

?>
```

That will end up returning a result that looks like:

```
{"result":"Hello World!"}
```

Now, that JSON can be consumed by your Objective-C code, e.g.:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]; // put your URL in here
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    // make sure there wasn't a connection error

    if (connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"%s: sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", __FUNCTION__, connectionError);
        return;
    }

    // parse the JSON data

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    // make sure there wasn't a JSON parsing error

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
        return;
    }

    // now grab the "result" value from the dictionary we parsed from the JSON
    // make sure to do all UI stuff on the main queue, though

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        self.label.text = jsonDictionary[@"result"];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: GREAT ROB !!! This would do the trick... Will try out the coding later but the conversion should work and I know were you are getting at. Thanks !!!